# Update table with value in a range of another table

Tags: mysql

I think this should be simple but I just can't seem to crack it with my limited experience.

I have a table (pos_data) with a column (timestamp) and another column (BinNo). I have a second table (time_intervals) with columns (IntervalSatert, IntervalEnd and BinNo).

I need to lookup the timestamp (in table pos_data) in the range between IntervalStart and IntervalEnd and assign the relevant BinNo in the time_interval table.

I tried an inner link but I'm unsure what to base the link on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an `update` with a `join` like this:

```
update pos_data d join
       time_intervals ti
       on d.timestamp between intervalStart and intervalend
    set d.BinNo = ti.BinNo;
```